# Chrome animation artifacts

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, css-animations

I use a simple animation that seems to work fine at first sight, but suffers from some artifacts. In [this video](https://youtu.be/cbo2A0FAveY) you'll see the artifacts in the first 15 seconds. Then I refresh the screen and the animation seems to work fine.

As you can see the artifacts appear as rectangular blocks:
[image: Example of the animation artifact]

You can also see the artifact for yourself, because it's still live on [our website](https://transferxl.com). It contains the following CSS animation:

```
animation-name: pulse-border,fade;
animation-duration: 2s,.5s;
animation-delay: 2s,2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite,1;
animation-direction: alternate,normal;
animation-fill-mode: none,backwards;
```

The rest of the element's CSS is:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
right: -20px;
bottom: -20px;
border: 15px solid white;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
content: '';
z-index: 0;
```

The pulse-border animation is defined like this:

```
@keyframes pulse-border {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.04); }
}
```

The artifacts don't always occur. Sometimes it works flawless, but sometimes I get issues. I have seen this issue only in Chrome, but both on OS X and Windows. When I disable and enable the `animation-name` in the developer tools, then the animation is fine again (but it might fail again after some scrolling).

I have also created a JSFiddle, but it doesn't show this artifact: https://jsfiddle.net/ramondeklein/ggk9vyjx/3/

This bug is already there for a while, but I haven't found a good workaround to fix it.

Comment: Could you please recreate this completely in the question itself, *including all relevant CSS (including the other keyframes) for the element*. The problem is only present when the element is scaled in from 0 thanks to `@keyframes bubble-appear`. If you remove that animation then there is no problem. I'm not sure this rendering issue can be prevented.

Comment: Also, this seems to only be a problem when the element is scaled from 0 *whilst over a background image*... it doesn't seem to have the same problem when scaled over a white background on initial page load.

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle, but the problem is that I only see it in my website. I haven't found the attribute and/or element that is causing this artifact.

Comment: No idea why this is happening, but I found the element to change as a workaround. (I can't recreate it so can't provide this as an answer). The element that is being pixelated is `transfer:before`... The pseudo-element. If you remove the box-shadow and border properties from it the problem goes away (or is sufficiently minor). I used `transfer:before {
 border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}` to test it, so try removing these properties.